# Update controller method not rendering json data in Laravel

Tags: forms, controller, laravel-5.8

I have a simple form with some text inputs and uploading photos with that form. Store method working very well but I'm doing something wrong in update method.

This is my store method which works fine:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    $post = new Post;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $post->who = $request->who;
    $post->when = $request->when;
    $post->where = $request->where;
    $post->body_text = $request->body;
    $post->embed = $request->embed;
    $post->status = "4";
    $post->tags = $request->tags;
    $post->slug = "asdasd";
    $post->ip = request()->ip();


    if($request->hasfile('photo'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('photo') as $image)
        {
            $name= time()."".$this->photo_san($image->getClientOriginalName());
            $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
        $post->photo = json_encode($data);
    }

    $post->save();

    $post->slug = $post->id."-".$this->make_slug($request->title);
    $post->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Well done.');
    return redirect()->route('archive');

}
```

And this is my update method which saves everything but photos:

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if(Auth::user()->role == 3 || Auth::user()->id == Post::find($id)->user_id){
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->user_id = $request->user()->id;
        $post->who = $request->who;
        $post->when = $request->when;
        $post->where = $request->where;
        $post->body_text = $request->body;
        $post->embed = $request->embed;
        $post->status = "4";
        $post->tags = $request->tags;
        $post->slug = $id."-".$this->make_slug($request->title);
        $post->ip = request()->ip();

        if($request->hasFile('photo'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('photo') as $image)
            {
                $name= time()."-edit-".$this->photo_san($image->getClientOriginalName());
                $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
            $post->photo = json_encode($data);
        }

        $post->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Well done.');
        return redirect()->route('new');
    }
    else
        Session::flash('error', 'Shame on you :( ');
        return redirect()->route('new');
}
```

When I'm updating any post, everything updating but photos and I don't have any idea what's wrong.
I don't know if it differs but I'm using Laravel 5,8

Comment: What do you mean by photo not getting updated? What should happen on image update?

Comment: In update method photo array turns empty. So I can't update photo cell in db.

Comment: I guess you are using `time()` in file path, due to which path is going to be unique. you have to save image url in db while creating it and then  on update you can delete image from that url and then create new one.

Comment: I'm using time() just for the sake of uniqueness of the file name. I'm storing just file's name, not path of the file.